# Serve static files via http with go

Tags: go

In my html I'm trying to include JS using

```
<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
```

I have also tried relative path (from server location)

```
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

and relative from the html file

My file structure

```
-js
    app.js
-templates
    index.html
hub.go
main.go
```

main.go is the server

```
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", rootHandler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

func rootHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    http.ServeFile(w, r, "Templates/index.html")
}
```

Am I missing something do I have to server css/js through server? or should the simple html work

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To serve files via http, define a FileServer for a directory and route it to, for example, `"/assets/"` using `http.Handle`. 
Following setup should work for you:

directory structure:

```
├── assets/
│   ├── js
│   └── css
├── templates/
└── main.go
```

main.go

```
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", rootHandler)
    http.Handle("/assets/", http.StripPrefix("/assets/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("assets"))))
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

func rootHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    http.ServeFile(w, r, "templates/index.html")
}
```

in your template file:

```
<script src="/assets/js/app.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have copied the exact structure you are using but I'm still getting 404 not found and image might help: http://imgur.com/a/J2ep0